# How to initialize automatically an array of pointers to function?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a set of functions:

```
int a1(int x, int, y)
{ do some stuff}

int a2(int x, int, y)
{ do some stuff}

//.........

int a100500(int x, int, y)
{ do some stuff}
```

Is there is a way to automatically initialize an array of pointers to function via FOR loop instead of explicitly typing a code like

```
int (*pfunc[100500])(int, int) = {a1, a2, ..., a1005000}
```

My first idea was to use #define directive in a following way:

```
#define z(n) a##n

// ..............

for (int i = 1; i< 100501;i++)
{ 
    pfunc[i] = z(i);
}
```

Unfortunately, z(i) becomes "ai" and not "a1", "a2", etc.

I hope, maybe some C-guru can help me with some advice.

Comment: boost has some macros to mock for loops in header; quite "ugly" but may help you if you really need it

Comment: OK, I gotta ask, why do you have 100k functions in the first place? Or rather, what’s your *actual* use-case?

Comment: Preprocessors is run as first step, so you get `ai` which is then sent to compiler. I would add a script (or a program) which create a `*.inc` and you include such file. Much more simple.

Comment: I think this can be done using some linker magic as done in linux kernel for example. Rusty on details

Comment: or with templates if you can use C++

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, of course I don't have 100500 functions. But I suddenly realized that it could be nice to manipulate with functions the same way as we can do with array of chars in alphabetical order, etc.

Comment: @tenghiz That’s why I was asking (and am still interested in) *actual* use-cases.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi, is it possible to expand your comment with more precise recommendations?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, it is a home assignment. I have to create an array with functions which can perform all math/trigonometry calculations. It must be an array with 10-15 entries.

Comment: @OznOg, Boost is only for C++, unfortunately. I am not very familiar with C++ yet.

Comment: 10-15 entries can be populated "manually" with much less effort than using some esoteric tricks, which won't probably be much appreciated by your instructor.

Comment: This is almost certainly an "XY problem". You are most likely using the wrong solution to the original problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think you should find a way to retrieve virtual address associated to the string representing your function within the ELF file (assumed this is your executable format)

Comment: I assume you have some external program to generate these functions ... make that also generate the table

Comment: @Emisilve86, actually, I had some similar idea. I know how to inspect stack content using asm, but it works only for variables. When I declare a function, where does its address go? Stack, heap or another kind of memory?

Comment: @tenghiz No. Stack and the Heap are virtual memory area which are addressable only at run-time, when OS validate pages for that at program start or upon mmap and brk calls. Functions addresses are included in the .text section but not the strings representing those functions. What I meant was to perform static analysis on ELF file by opening it as a common file in order to retrieve in some way the aforementioned strings, but it was only an hint cause I've not much experience, and you should find a way to parse this file correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding @Giacomo Catenazzi's comment, consider the following (not great) python script:

```py
# generate_funcs.py
import sys
with open('funcs.inc', 'w') as f:
    f.write(',\n'.join('a{}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(int(sys.argv[1]))))
```

Executed with the no. of your functions (`python generate_funcs.py 100500`), would produce a file called `funcs.inc` with:

```
a1,
a2,
...
a100500
```

You can then include it in your C code:

```c
int (*pfunc[])(int, int) = {
#include "funcs.inc"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I was sincerely persuaded that this is a trivial problem and I was just lacking a deeper knowledge of the language in order to implement my wish in a couple of lines of code. Your answer suggests that the solution must be different if I work on Windows platform. Heavens...